# Empty the textfield value after UIAlertView popUp in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextfield

I have a text field. If it has wrong values then it may show the alert values and also make the text field empty, but when I use:

```
textField.text = @"";
```

after alertView my app hangs and crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

but when i use `textField.text = @"1";` then it works fine, but I want the text field to be empty. How do I do this?

```
-(void)textFieldTextDidChangeClinicMarkup:(UITextField*)tf{

    NSString*test=clinicMarkupTextField.text;

    if([test isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        NSString*value=@"1";

        appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;
    }
    else if([test isEqualToString:@"1.5"]){
        NSString*value=@"1.5";

        appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;
    }
    else if([test isEqualToString:@"2"]){
        NSString*value=@"2";

        appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;
    }
    else if([test isEqualToString:@"2.5"]){
        NSString*value=@"2.5";

        appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;
    }
    else if([test isEqualToString:@"3"]){
        NSString*value=@"3";

        appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;
    }
    else if([test length] >=3 || [test floatValue] > 3 || [test floatValue] <1 )  {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Clinic Markup can only be $1, $1.5, $2, $2.5 and $3 " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        clinicalMArkupTextfield.text=@"";
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you validate data when user confirms it.I mean when textFieldDidEndEditing is called?

Comment: how to confirm can you tell me please me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is might be called because of you have registered it for text change notification.

```
clinicalMArkupTextfield.text=@"";
```

While you assign blank value by above line, this function will be called again (due to text change notification). Now, none of your condition is satisfied, so it will again come to last else if statement. And it might fall in infinite loop and create a probable crash.

Otherwise, there seems to be nothing wrong.

Comment: Using textfield delegate method. shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Comment: The code where you are creating text field, assign its delegate property to self. textField.delegate = self; Now, add above function and do the stuff with in it.

Comment: its not working i am doing in the same for other textfileds there it works fine as i have done in above code

Answer (score 1):

Use textfield delegate methods:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *finalString = [textfield.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

    if([finalString isEqualToString:@"anything"])
    {
        // Show alertBox......
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: then you should use :- [textfield.text retain].

Comment: where  may use this reatain can u tell me please

Comment: clinicalMArkupTextfield.text=@"";
[clinicalMArkupTextfield.text retain];